# Huge memory usage in ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have these functions called in a thread that draw a NSView:

```
+(NSFont *)customFontWithName:(NSString *)fontName AndSize:(float)fontSize
{

NSData *data = [[[NSDataAsset alloc]initWithName:fontName] data];
CGDataProviderRef fontProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

CGFontRef cgFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontProvider);
CGDataProviderRelease(fontProvider);
NSDictionary *fontsizeAttr=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fontSize], NSFontSizeAttribute,
                            nil];
CTFontDescriptorRef fontDescriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)fontsizeAttr);
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(cgFont, 0, NULL, fontDescriptor);
CFRelease(fontDescriptor);
CGFontRelease(cgFont);

NSFont* retval= (__bridge NSFont*)font;
CFRelease(font);
return retval;
}
```

and this:

```
+(NSAttributedString*) createCurrentTextWithString:(NSString *)string AndMaxLenght:(float)length AndMaxHeight:(float)maxHeight AndColor:(NSColor *)color AndFontName: (NSString*) fontName
{


float dim=0.1;

NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[CustomFont customFontWithName:fontName AndSize:dim], NSFontAttributeName,color, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

 NSAttributedString * currentText=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes: dictionary];


while([currentText size].width<maxLength&&[currentText size].height<maxHeight)
{

    dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[CustomFont customFontWithName:fontName AndSize:dim], NSFontAttributeName,color, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    currentText=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes: retval];


    dim+=0.1;

}

return currentText;

}
```

All the objects created in these functions were correctly deallocated and I can't find memory leaks, but this code caused an huge use of memory (many gigabytes) and I can't understand why. Please help.

Comment: Is your current text too big? try to return - (__bridge NSFont*)font - directly instead of using a NSFont

Comment: Avoid autoreleased objects. Use `[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:]` instead of `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]`. And/or use `@autoreleasepool{}` in loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. For some reasons, that I don't know, the code:

```
NSData *data = [[[NSDataAsset alloc]initWithName:fontName] data];
CGDataProviderRef fontProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
CGFontRef cgFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontProvider);
```

allocs large memory that will not be deallocate any more. So I create a static variable CGFontRef for each custom font I have. This is the only way I found:

```
static CGFontRef font1;
....
static CGFontRef font;

+(CGFontRef) getFontWithValue: (int) value
{
 switch (value)
{
    case 1:
        return font1;
        break;
        ...
    case n:
        return fontn;
    default:
        return NULL;
}
}
```

And

```
+(NSFont*) customFontWithName:(int)fontName AndSize:(float)fontSize
{
NSDictionary *fontsizeAttr=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fontSize], NSFontSizeAttribute,
                            nil];
CTFontDescriptorRef fontDescriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)fontsizeAttr);
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont([CustomFont getFontWithValue:fontName], 0, NULL, fontDescriptor);
CFRelease(fontDescriptor);
NSFont* retval= (__bridge NSFont*)font;
CFRelease(font);
return retval;

}
```

I still don't understand why there is this memory leak and this is not a solution, but only a trick, but it works.